# Best practice for ebook with large number of chapters (e.g. in thousands)

Tags: epub, creation, table-of-contents

I am trying to create an ebook with about 1300 chapters. The content itself is not that large (~7MB of raw text), but they are broken down over 1300 chapters or so. Each chapter is about 20-40 short paragraphs.

Ideally, I would like to preserve the chapters themselves as distinct HTML files within the epub archive. The main concern I have is regarding the table of content page. If I created a TOC with all 1300 items, it'd be useless having to scroll through the whole thing. Would it make sense to say break it up by 200 chapters, such that the first item would contain 1-200, second would contain 201-400, etc?

Any other recommendations for when creating such an epub?

Answer (score 0):

A web post about epub expandable TOC was discussed at the following link (and there's an example epub too).
The discussion there might yield a solution for you, or at least be worth reading (and view the example epub they have provided there):  [MobileRead link](https://www.mobileread.com/forums/showthread.php?t=279639)

As a side thought...you might be able to place the TOC chapter links as two links per horizontal line. Methods are limited: Possibly via 'column-count', or display inline, or using float property. Flexbox no. Doing parallel TOC links may be a challenge in Amazon KDP, but yes on Kobo epub. Here is a JSFiddle example:
[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zircon/xp5v9wu4)
Welcome to ESE.